# Solr SearchResultItem indexer does not resolve dynamic field name on custom index

Tags: solr, index

Background: Sitecore 8.2.6, SOLR 5.4.1

I need to use class indexer to resolve field name for SOLR.

To simplify issue description let me provide next code snippet:

```
var fieldName = ..method parameter.ToLowerInvariant();
var products = context.GetQueryable<SearchItemResult>()
                    .Where(x => x[fieldName] != null)
                    .ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

For example, fieldName value that is passed to predicate is "shape". Index actually contains field `shape_s`.

The issue is such - when I use standard `sitecore_web_index`, in *Search.log* I can observe query where this `shape` is actually resolved to `shape_s`, and query does its job. But when I switch to `custom sitecore_products_index` which is based on web database and indexes just specific set of templates via `<include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate">`, in Search.log I get error message '["undefined field shape"]'.

As far as I can think after all my experiments the only superficial difference is that web index contains all the templates, but custom product index contains reduced set of them.

If I inherit SearchItemResult to my custom class and define some property decorated with IndexField attribute, everything works fine if I use this approach. But in this specific task I have to use dynamic field name passed as parameter, so I want to use C# indexer for a SearchItemResult class to resolve this into SOLR's field name.

Comment: What does your index config look like?

Comment: Actually it is a copy of sitecore/contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration node with some set of templates specified

Comment: is the field "shape" a computed field or it is present on the item in sitecore?

Comment: It is a field in sitecore item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on previous projects, when using `Where(x => x[fieldName] != null)`, the fieldName should match the one from the Solr Index. From your question, if you pass `Where(x => x["shape_s"] != null)`, it should work.

Since you have dynamic fields being passed to the search context, you will need to get the field type. You can get it by using

```
var fieldNameWithType = context.Index.FieldNameTranslator.GetIndexFieldName("shape")
```

Solr will return the value `shape_s`. While debugging, you can see in the dictionary `typeFieldMap` the list of all fields how they are in the Solr Index.

Your code will look like below

```
var fieldName = ..method parameter.ToLowerInvariant();
var fieldNameWithType = context.Index.FieldNameTranslator.GetIndexFieldName(fieldName)
var products = context.GetQueryable<SearchItemResult>()
                .Where(x => x[fieldNameWithType] != null)
                .ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Many thanks @Hishaam! I was thinking about this kind of solution but did not find it because of lack of search API knowledge.
Actually I've made workaround to the issue in different way - I've added field for 'shape' into index config file, just like this:
    <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
        ....
        <field fieldName="shape" returnType="string" />
        ....
    </fieldNames>
and it started get recognized by Solr.