# Solr query works in the web UI, not when invoked though code

Tags: solr, indexing

I'm on **Solr 4.10.4, Sitecore 8.1 160519**.

I have a query used internally by my application that returns 0 records.

In the Search.log I can see that same query; if I copy the querystring value to the Solr web UI, it returns the results I expect from it.

```
?q=((_path:(0de95ae441ab4d019eb067441b7c2450) AND enabled_b:(True))
AND _templatename:("Base Person"))
&start=0
&rows=20
&fl=*,score
&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)
```

This is the C# code that performs the query. It's the same code that worked for Lucene.

```
var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<BasePerson>();

filter = filter
    .And(i => i.ItemAncestors.Contains(GlobalDefinitions.Data.ContentRoot))
    .And(i => i.Enabled);

Expression<Func<BasePerson, object>>[] facetsFilter = {
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedLocation],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedDivisions],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedSpecialisms],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedCapitals],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedHoldings],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedIntelligences],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedStrategies],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedConsultings],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedCapabilities],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.PeerGroup],
    i => i[GlobalDefinitions.IndexFields.ParsedSectors] };

filter =
    filter.And(item => (item.TemplateId == GlobalDefinitions.Templates.BasePersonTemplate.Id));

PageInfo pageInfo = null;
if (!noPaging) {
    pageInfo = new PageInfo() {
        Page = page,
        PageSize = pageSize
    };
}

var query = SearchContext.GetQueryable<BasePerson>();
query = query.Where(filter);

foreach (var facet in facets) {
    query = query.FacetOn(facet);
}

query = query.Page(pageInfo.Page, pageInfo.PageSize);

var results = query.GetResults();
```

**Question**

Any clues on what could possibly cause this behavior, or what could help me to troubleshoot it?

**EDIT**

On request, I added the C# code that performs the query.

**EDIT 2**

Apparently, and surprisingly, the culprits is facets. I modified the code above to include the faceting, that I had removed as I didn't imagine it would make a difference. After switching the *PeerGroup* facet to the Solr index name, from:

```
i => i["peer_group"]
```

to

```
i => i["peer_group_sm"]
```

everything worked. Go figure.

Comment: Have you tried with lowercase template name? or replacing template name with template id?

Comment: I will right away.

Comment: Same results: returns 0 results, but if I retrieve the query from Search.log and use it in the Web UI it returns what I expect.

Comment: Can you post your code that is not returning the results?

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: I found the culprit - it was facets; facets that I did not include in the code above because I thought they would not make a difference. This is made even more puzzling by the fact that, of the many facets I have, most of them don't use the Solr index names (with the "_sm" etc. suffixes). And yet, one of those in particular, when changed to the Solr version, makes all the difference.

Comment: Hmmm, you shouldn't have to specify it with `_sm` as that is Solr specific.. though likely won't hurt anything to leave it that way.

Comment: Indeed, I am very much puzzled as of why this is necessary, and in faceting of all places! I could not believe it when I saw it, I had to narrow it down but there's no denying it: if I change that bit of code with and without _sm, it works and it doesn't work respectively.

Comment: You could add it as an attribute. Or you can read the name dynamically as suggested here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13092/solr-searchresultitem-indexer-does-not-resolve-dynamic-field-name-on-custom-inde/13111#13111

Comment: Can you try it as `i["peer group"]` with a space instead of the underscore?

Comment: I can, but what makes you think it would work?

Comment: I would recommend adding an answer with your solution, since you were able to solve it.

Comment: I will soon enough.